# Spring functional bean registration of @Repository interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-function

I migrated a Spring-Cloud-Function to use Functional Bean Registration.
I can register the `Function` that contains my application logic.
However my logic should be able to autowire a dynamodbRepository which I currently defined like this:

```
@EnableScan
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<CodingTip, String> {

        List<Book> findAllByAuthor(String author);
}
```

Since I am not scanning for beans anymore no bean is created of type `BookRepository`. This means that I have to register it myself. But I do not want to define the implementations of all the CRUD methods.

Currently I could write:

```
context.registerBean("repository", BookRepository.class, () -> new BookRepository(){ ... });
```

How would I register the BookRepository bean while still maintaining the advantages of all the CRUD methods being implemented for me?

Comment: you can use ``@ComponentScan(basePackages ="com.yours.repos")`` to load all your components(including CrudRepository) in this directory into spring bean container.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this incubator project called [Spring Fu](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-fu). Although it is written in Kotlin, it might help you find a way to do this.
Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-fu/blob/master/samples/kofu-reactive-mongodb/src/main/kotlin/com/sample/Repositories.kt) to see how Sébastien did it with a MongoDB database.
Creating a DynamoDB client and an implementation instead of using an annotated interface would be the way forward I guess.

Hope that helps! :)